# Pandas: Create header grouping columns in groups of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I'm learning about Multiindex, groupBy, turples, reading similar questions on Stak Overflow, on Google search and Youtube tutorials. Came into a complex point.

How can I group a number of unknown columns in groups of two. This is what I have. Header and one row:

```
patterns    responses   patterns    responses   patterns   ...  
hello       hi          Where?      here        When?      ...
```

And I'm looking to create a header over the header that groups in two columns like:

```
a                       a                       a
patterns    responses   patterns    responses   patterns   ...  
hello       hi          Where?      here        When?      ...
```

Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your DataFrame contains initially an "ordinary" (single level)
index on columns:

```
  patterns responses patterns.1 responses.1 patterns.2 responses.2
0    hello        hi     Where?        here      When?       there
```

Note that *Pandas*, e.g. on reading a DataFrame from CSV file, by default
appends numbers to columns with repeating names, but for us only the
first 2 (without numeric suffix) will be needed.

Note also that column titles at the added (top) level should not be the same.
To be able to tell apart consecutive pairs of columns, I took the approach
to name them *Q1*, *Q2* and so on.

To have a MultiIndex on columns, you can proceed as follows:

```
cols = df.columns
nPairs = len(cols) // 2
h1 = [ f'Q{i}' for i in range(1, nPairs + 1) ]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([h1, cols[:2]])
```

The result is:

```
        Q1                 Q2                 Q3          
  patterns responses patterns responses patterns responses
0    hello        hi   Where?      here    When?     there
```

Other possibilities to create a MultiIndex are e.g. *from_arrays* and
*from_tuples*. Read about them and practice while learning *Pandas*.

## Edit following the question in a comment

One of possible causes of your exception is that your input file contains:

- An index column, posiibly without name.
- Then a number of column pairs (*patterns* / *responses*).

Then, if you read it using *read_csv*, you should order to "convert" this column
into an index:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', index_col=[0])
```

Then the number of "actual" columns will be less by one, so my code should
run with no exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Yes! I have an Index column but due it comes from changing first row to header looks a bit to weird thought would confuse here...

Comment: After running the code got this error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2103 elements, new values have 2102 elements` Could that be because the columns number is odd? or because of the Index column?

Comment: Hi again. tried several times. save it again on csv file before using your solution and it doesn't work if columns is odd.

Comment: My solution was written for the case when there is even number of columns, just as in your example.

Comment: Hi @Valdi_Bo y wrote an unkown number of columns. Sorry if it was not clear enough...

Comment: That is why I'm trying to figure out something like this: `if cols%2 !=  0: df.iloc[:, :-1]`